# Remove a merge/commit in git

Tags: git

Using git I merged a branch to master and now after a few weeks and many commits I'd like to remove that feature/branch. How do I do it? it doesn't seem trivial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938301/remove-specific-commit

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do. Do you want to undo the merge commit or do you just want to remove the now obsolete branch?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to completely remove it from you history, you could do the following:

1. `git rebase -i <commit to remove>^`
2. This will open your default editor (usually vi) with a list of commits, with the one you want to remove first. Remove it from the list, save, and quit. This should no rebase your branch without the commit you want to remove.

A "safer" approach is to leave the history in tact, so you can show that this feature used to exist, and was purposely removed. Just use `git revert <commit to remove>`. This will create an additional patch that undoes the commit you want to get rid of. The main advantage is that you can edit the commit message, and explain why this feature is being removed.

Comment: Sounds to me like undoing the merge might be the cleaner solution, the branch still exists anyway?

Comment: Yes, such a change won't remove the branch.

Comment: The list of commits does not include the merge commit in my case.

Comment: @barfuin you probably forgot the caret at the end of the `<commit to remove>^`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to revert a `merge` commit, here is what you have to do.

1. First, check the `git log` to find your merge commit's id. You'll also find multiple parent ids associated with the merge (see image below).

[image]

Note down the merge commit id shown in yellow.
The parent IDs are the ones written in the next line as `Merge: parent1 parent2`. Now...

Short Story:

2. Switch to branch on which the merge was made. Then Just do the `git revert <merge commit id> -m 1` which will open a `vi` console for entering commit message. Write, save, exit, done!

Long story:

2. Switch to branch on which the merge was made. In my case, it is the `test` branch and I'm trying to remove the `feature/analytics-v3` branch from it.
3. `git revert` is the command which reverts any commit. But there is a nasty trick when reverting a `merge` commit. You need to enter the `-m` flag otherwise it will fail. From here on, you need to decide whether you want to revert your branch and make it look like exactly it was on `parent1` or `parent2` via:

`git revert <merge commit id> -m 1` (reverts to `parent2`)

`git revert <merge commit id> -m 2` (reverts to `parent1`)

You can git log these parents to figure out which way you want to go and that's the root of all the confusion.

Comment: Just to say that the git revert worked perfectly on my case to rever an git merge of a feature branch onto another feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

For full control over the operation and to preserve any merge commits you want to keep along the way, the modern approach is to use

`git rebase -i -r`